# GTK lebel text wrap for some languages

Tags: fonts, gtk, font-size, gtk3, pango

I am using gtk_label_set_line_wrap on label where text is long and text is in some other language.
but in output text wraps and text in first and second line are overlapping for some chars.
Any help how i can increase gap between wrapped text lines.
Note : i can not add "\n" in text.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question currently makes it difficult for other users to give you quick and helpful answers. Please read the guide on how to ask a good question and edit your question above to meet these guidelines - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The OP apparently wants to increase line spacing in a multiline label. It would be a duplicate of [Gtk3 label line spacing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139645/gtk3-label-line-spacing), but SO doesn't allow marking as dup of that one as the previous question doesn't have an answer. Apparently line spacing cannot be changed.

Comment: i found the solution using Pangoattribute on label 
PangoAttrList *attr_list;
 PangoAttribute *attr;
attr_list=pango_attr_list_new();
attr=pango_attr_rise_new (20000);
 pango_attr_list_insert(attr_list,attr);
 gtk_label_set_attributes(GTK_LABEL(label),attr_list);